# Como mapear uma pagina html no Spring MVC

Tags: java, html, java-ee, spring

Tenho um projeto Spring MVC que irá fornecer o serviço rest para o front-end.
Só que ao criar uma pagina .html o projeto não a reconhece e sempre da 404. Exite alguma configuração que eu deva fazer a mais para o spring mvc reconhecer o .html?

arquivo servlet-context.xml:

```
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" /> /*ja mudei para .html mas não funcionou*/
</beans:bean>
```

E o arquivo web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Porque a URL pattern no `web.xml` está com somente um "/" ?

Comment: Posta como que o controller está chamando esta página.

Comment: Olá, em que pasta encontra-se suas views HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Não adianta você adicionar a extensão .html na configuração do `InternalResourceViewResolver` do Spring, pois ele é usado para renderizar arquivos que precisam de engines de renderização como é o caso do JSP, nesse caso a configuração que você necessita adicionar é essa :

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/meusArquivosAssets/**" location="/meusArquivosAssets/" />
```

Comment: Mas em qual arquivo?

Comment: no servlet-context.xml.